# Horizontally centering tabs in Material-UI AppBar with ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, appbar, center-align

I'm building a React App with Material-UI and can't figure out how to center the 3 tabs within the blue AppBar. Currently, they are all left-aligned, as such:

https://i.imgur.com/MjQIuBl.png (can't embed images yet, my apologies)

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  {/* Tabs */}
  <AppBar position="static" color="primary" style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>
    <Tabs
      fullWidth={true}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      indicatorColor="secondary"
    >
      <Tab label="Passenger" icon={Icons.seatIcon} component={Link} to="/passenger" />
      <Tab label="Driver" icon={Icons.driverIcon} component={Link} to="/driver" />
      <Tab label="Settings" icon={Icons.settingsIcon} component={Link} to="/settings" />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
</div>
```

I've experimented with a lot of different CSS properties from similar questions but haven't gotten close. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try adding "centered" to the Tabs components, like this:

```
    <div>
  {/* Tabs */}
  <AppBar position="static" color="primary" style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>
    <Tabs
      fullWidth={true}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      indicatorColor="secondary"
      centered
    >
      <Tab label="Passenger" icon={Icons.seatIcon} component={Link} to="/passenger" />
      <Tab label="Driver" icon={Icons.driverIcon} component={Link} to="/driver" />
      <Tab label="Settings" icon={Icons.settingsIcon} component={Link} to="/settings" />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! So what's the difference between `centered` and something like `align-content: center`?

Comment: @ZachBrown `align-content` is used to control flexbox. `centered` is a prop for the `Tabs` component which applies certain styles defined in Material UI to get the tabs to be centered

Comment: If `fullWidth={true}` does not work try `variant="fullWidth"`; It was for my case

Answer (score 2):

If the `centered` property is not working for you, you may try the CSS API (tested with Material-UI 3.7.0). This also gives you a bit more control if you desire:

```js
import { Tabs, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

export const CenteredTabs = withStyles({
  flexContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})(Tabs);
```

Comment: This snippet is outdated. Material-UI is now available in version 4.8 and a lot has changed since Dec 2018

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem in newer versions of MUI:

```
<Tabs
     sx={{ margin: "auto" }}
>
```

Comment: Adding `margin: 'auto',` to my sx prop worked perfectly thank you I had tried the with flexbox and it just wasn't working.